# Missing portal from mission

Tags: ingress

Since pogo started, a lot of portals removed. Some of them was part of mission(s). The big problem is, that some of these missions is part of a big banner.

Let's say, there are a really big banner, for example with 60 missions.

I started it, and when I finished with the 49th, in the 50th, there is a non existent portal. What now?

So my question is, what happens, if there is a removed portal from a mission. Can I complete that mission, or I just messed up my profile page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be playable even if there is a deleted portal:

[If a portal is missing (deleted maybe?) and a mission uses it, what happens to a mission?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/4vegzs/if_a_portal_is_missing_deleted_maybe_and_a/)

In this reddit post, somebody mentioned that if the number of portals are less than the minimum required number of portals for a mission then the mission will be deleted automatically.

This last information is not confirmed. I heard rumors that if all the portals were removed from a mission and you start it, you did immediately finish it.

Answer (score 3):

If the mission still exists, it should be playable and appear in your profile as normal. (Unless the author has been an evil SOB and requires details rom a mow-deleted portal in a subsequent question. Fortunately most mission authors are nicer than that.)